# OmniFaces UnmappedResourceHandler seems to leak resources when composite components are used

Tags: jsf-2, memory-leaks, composite-component, omnifaces, unmappedresourcehandler

It seems `UnmappedResourceHandler` is loading composite components xhtml files within the resources folder. The result seems a gradually increasing memory leak.

The leak can be found within `FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.metadataCache`.
It relies on a hashmap and when above handler is used `UnmappedResources` are used as the key for `CompositeComponentBeanInfo` instances.

If the `UnmappedResourceHandler` isn't used, the key contains `ResourceImpl`. The difference is that `UnmappedResource` does not implement `equals()` as `ResourceImpl` does:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    ResourceImpl resource = (ResourceImpl) o;
    return resourceInfo.equals(resource.resourceInfo);
}
```

So problem seems that in the first case `CompositeComponentBeanInfo` is added again and again to the `metadataCache`. In the second everything works as expected.

Anyone else can confirm this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UnmappedResourceHandler` memory leak on composite components is confirmed and has been solved by [this commit](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/38d03300cc194ba0a66272c5a6d462f0f3b0b55d) for 2.1, [this commit](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/fedc70a5a7431b1a31371629ce308ca7c2b6cd6c) for 1.11 and [this commit](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/d3daff29ed41da945efc0d78b771ada80f9978a7) for 1.8.3.

All versions are as of today available in Maven.